# Alternatives to "the last/final word"?

Tags: expressions, synonyms

Is there any alternative to the idiom "having the [last/final word](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the%20last/final%20word) on something", perhaps emphasizing the fact that the speaker's intervention has effectively closed discussion on a topic?

In other languages, e.g. Italian, I have seen metaphoric expressions such as "putting a tombstone on the question".

Comment: The Italian saying you are referring to “metterci una pietra sopra” doesn’t mean “the final word” but it refers to “stop thinking/talking about something”.

Comment: @user66974 I was actually referring to the expression "(mettere) una pietra tombale" on something, as seen e.g. [here](https://www.globalist.it/intelligence/2022/07/16/giulio-regeni-una-pietra-tombale-sul-processo-draghi-e-di-maio-hanno-qualcosa-da-dire) "una pietra tombale sul processo", meaning the issue has been definitley closed.

Comment: This is the idiomatic expression commonly used in Italian : https://sapere.virgilio.it/modi-di-dire/metterci-una-pietra-sopra-1086 - the sense of the expression used in the article expresses a sense of defeat, of not being able to go ahead with that issue. Which is different from “a final word”.

Comment: I reckon the example provided was not very clear. "Metterci una pietra sopra", however, is quite different from "mettere una pietra tombale su una questione", with the second one being nearer to "having the last word on something", i.e. _peremptorily_ closing a discussion (further examples via [Google Books search](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=una+pietra+tombale+sulla+questione)). Anyway, it seems there are no similar metaphors in English.

Comment: I agree probably there is no  similar metaphor, anyway, just to be clear, in the Italian saying “metterci una pietra sopra” the stone in the saying is just the short for tombstone. https://www.perchesidice.it/perche-si-dice-metterci-una-pietra-sopra/

Comment: A [mic drop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mic_drop) is also similar, with metaphorical uses, but not quite the same connotation.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "case closed" (or "I rest my case") is often used in similar contexts, to indicate that a speaker is done making an argument for a particular point of view.

Answer (score 0):

A common idiom is, "stick a fork in it, it's done". This means any further discussion or action is superfluous, and is generally used in celebratory fashion. There is also, "put this to bed". This means to assertively end a course of discussion or action, and is generally more forceful or demanding.